# Objective C++ copying a struct

Tags: objective-c++

The code is super simple:

```
SomeStruct varA = varB;
```

where SomeStruct is

```
{
  NSString * name;
  NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *_Nullable dict;
}
```

When I look at my code in debug mode at exact that step, I see the name being correctly set to point at the name object in varA (and when I expand it up it has the right string value too) but the dictionary is null in varB with <error: parent is NULL>. What did I do wrong?

I actually tried

```
  varB.dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  varB.dict = varA.dict;
```

But that did nothing either, varB in debug mode still showed 0x0000 (ie, null) in the field dict, and when I click on it still said error is parent is NULL

Comment: Are you actually experiencing any unexpected runtime behaviour? Or could this just be a case of the debugger getting confused? I don't see anything in particular wrong with the code fragment you posted. If you're actually seeing some runtime behaviour you're not expecting, could you try to put together a minimal reproducible sample for us to try?

Comment: Actually relooking at this I'm suspecting it might be the debugger bugging out. The rest of my code functioned normally and the thing I was trying to fix doesn't actually relate to this part. Thanks for the help anyways!